# PhpWord add footer content from specific page

Tags: php, docx, doc, phpword

I am using simple code to add footer to DOCX, or DOC document via PhpWord library.

```
$footer->addPreserveText('My Sample Content');
```

But I want to start adding this content from for example page 6. How can I achieve this result?
So first 5 pages footer will be blank, another pages from page 6 will be with that content.